# TestBed configureTestingModule define imports, declarations, providers, and pipes common to all spec.ts in one Module - pattern

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

Is there a **optimal way to define imports, declarations, providers common to all spec.ts**  (i.e modules common to all specs one place define like we do it in @NgModule) in one place like we do in @NgModule for application **Unit tests**.

Note : Call configureTestingModule within a beforeEach so that TestBed can reset itself to a base state before each test runs. as on doc

Here in one of my test spec.ts i have to load same modules components and directives ..etc which is used by some other spec too.

```
describe('Component: Login', () => {
let loginFixture, loginComponent, loginComponentElement,loginComponentDebugElement;
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialRootModule, ModalModule, DatepickerModule,
    DropdownModule, AccordionModule], //--> here we load n number of mudoles 
  declarations: [LoginComponent, LoginHeaderComponent, LoginColumnComponent, LoginColumnContentComponent,
    LoginStatusLaneComponent, LoginSettingsComponent,
    LoginLaneComponent, SortableDirective, WindowHeightDirective, ConfirmDirective, ConfirmPopoverComponent, ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogDirective],         //--> here we load n number of components directive and piper          
  providers: [LoginComponent,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    ComponentLoaderFactory,
    ConfirmOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    },
    {provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService},
    {provide: AppContextService, useClass: MockAppContextService},
    {provide: NotificationsService, useClass: MockNotificationsService},
    {provide: PositioningService}]       //--> here we load n number of services    
}).compileComponents();
loginFixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
loginComponent = loginFixture.componentInstance; 
loginComponentElement = LoginFixture.nativeElement;
loginComponentDebugElement = LoginFixture.debugElement;
}));

 it('should have a defined component', () => {
expect(LoginComponent).toBeDefined();
});
});
```

Note : [Git Angular issue TestBed.configureTestingModule Performance Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12409)

**Is there any pattern to make it common like loading all this modules components etc in starting  before running all spec.ts** file and inject respective dependency for each specs . Any help would be great.

Comment: I have same thinking. and I've ask on SOja. https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34780/ (no response as of May 22. if I get any info, share it here.)

Answer (score 4):

My answer is incomplete you have come to expect.
But I hope if it can help you even a little.

router-stubs.ts

```
//----------Default Import------------
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
...snip...
export const test_imports = [
               BrowserModule,
               FormsModule,
               HttpModule,
               BrowserAnimationsModule
             ];
```

each test.spec.ts

```
import { test_imports }   from '../testing/router-stubs';
..snip..
      imports: [test_imports],
```

but providers/declarations can't use in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define TestBed.configureTestingModule before the describe method. so it can be available globally. So now your test cases will look like this.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, MaterialRootModule, ModalModule, DatepickerModule,
    DropdownModule, AccordionModule], //--> here we load n number of mudoles 
  declarations: [LoginComponent, LoginHeaderComponent, LoginColumnComponent, LoginColumnContentComponent,
    LoginStatusLaneComponent, LoginSettingsComponent,
    LoginLaneComponent, SortableDirective, WindowHeightDirective, ConfirmDirective, ConfirmPopoverComponent, ConfirmationDialogComponent,
    ConfirmationDialogDirective],         //--> here we load n number of components directive and piper          
  providers: [LoginComponent,
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    ComponentLoaderFactory,
    ConfirmOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    },
    {provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService},
    {provide: AppContextService, useClass: MockAppContextService},
    {provide: NotificationsService, useClass: MockNotificationsService},
    {provide: PositioningService}]       //--> here we load n number of services    
}).compileComponents();

describe('Component: Login', () => {
  let loginFixture, loginComponent, loginComponentElement, loginComponentDebugElement;
  beforeEach(async(() => {

    loginFixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    loginComponent = loginFixture.componentInstance;
    loginComponentElement = LoginFixture.nativeElement;
    loginComponentDebugElement = LoginFixture.debugElement;
  }));

  it('should have a defined component', () => {
    expect(LoginComponent).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to go for a separate library just to achieve this. You can create a global TestBed just by creating a common angular module where you can define a utility method. This utility method creates the TestBed which you can then reuse across all your spec files.

You can refer to the answer below which also includes sample code: (Possible duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/a/64835814/4184651